# What gazebo plugins should I use for robotic arm in ROS2-humble?

Tags: ros2, robotic-arm, urdf, gazebo-plugin, ros-humble

Im using ROS2-humble
what plugins, interfaces. should i add, and why?
the urdf file:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Shai, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your specific application but common plugins are:

- `gazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher` , since the `joint_state_publisher` nor the gui version work with gazebo, you need this plugin to replace them.
- `gazebo_ros2_control` to use `ros2_control` and `ros2_controllers` packages to control the manipulator.

Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/ZeinBarhoum/chess_manipulator) for an example for using ROS2 and Gazebo to simulate and control a manipulator.